# Slicing an R vector

Tags: r

For the code

```
nobs <- 10
nskip <- 3
x <- 1:nobs    
print(x)    
print(x[4:10])    
print(x[nskip+1:nobs])
```

the output is

```
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10    
[1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10   
[1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 NA NA NA
```

I don't understand why the last two lines of output differ -- why are there NA's?

Comment: I thought incorrectly that this operator precedence issue was in the R-FAQ. However, another error (relating to the '-' and '^' operators) was there, and the advice to check ?Syntax is still valid here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put parentheses around (nskip+1), the order of operations is off as you have it.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved. R and Fortran 95 are different in this respect.

Comment: Don't I know that well :).

Comment: If you're happy with this answer, can you approve it?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some parentheses. Look at the sequence you get when you do this

```
nskip + 1:nobs
# 4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
```

It's generating the sequence from 1 to `nobs` and then adding `nskip` to each element. You are getting `NA`s because elements 11 to 13 do not exist within `x`.

You need to include parentheses to produce the correct sequence.

```
print(x[(nskip+1):nobs])
```

Now, the part between the parentheses gets evaluated first, so that the sequence is then generated between `(nskip + 1)` and `nobs`.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use `seq`, which also allows more generic slicing with a jump value.

```
nobs  <- 12
nskip <- 3
njump <- 4
x     <- 1:nobs    
print(x[seq(nskip+1, nobs, 1)])
print(x[seq(nskip+1, nobs, njump)])
```

Output

```
[1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
[1]  4  8 12
```

Learning the operator precedence is always helpful!

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html